# Why does Lens made of Two Materials form only Two Images?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I was solving a test this morning and came across this question. Now by intuition, I know that there should be only two images formed. Rays shall converge through the upper section of the lens to form an image at Principal Focus 1; rays shall converge through the lower section to form an image at Principal Focus 2. Since the refractive indices of both sections are different, they shall have different positions for their principal foci.

[image]

It was here when I realised that the rays refracted through section 1 would still intersect with the rays refracted through section 2. My question is, if this logic holds true, why must there be only 2 images formed? Shouldn't an infinite number of images be formed? Here is a diagram illustrating my point of view.

[image]

Why is this logic wrong, and why should an infinite number of images not be formed? Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.
Thankyou.